# How secure is PFConfig to store secret keys (used in processing payments for instance)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How secure is to use PFConfig to retrieve secret keys stored as Environment Parameters in the Parse Server?

```
PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock{
      (config: PFConfig?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        configuration.parameters = config!
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I am having the same question but find it difficult to find an answer. Thanks. T

Comment: I am not sure that Parse can be securely protected. You have to protect the master key. I try to obfuscate this string encrypting it outside the app, storing the encrypted string in the Plist and decrypting it in a function to supply it as needed. I am not sure how secure this is. If you can protect the master key you are probably secure using PFConfig.